# need to parse between second underscore and first hyphen of the text using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have an `rpm` file, e.g. `abc_defg_hijd-3.29.0-2_el6_11h.txt`.

I need to parse the words between the 2nd underscore `_` and first hyphen `-` of the above text,
so the required output will be `hijd`.

I was able to parse the above with `sed` for the above, but it worked only for the above example and I have filenames which differ a little, hence I would like to explicitly parse between the second underscore and first hyphen.

Comment: I have a **rpm** file like this, `abc.. .txt` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this sed command (on Mac):

```
sed -E 's/^[^_]*_[^_]*_([^-]*)-.*$/\1/'
```

OR (on Linux):

```
sed -r 's/^[^_]*_[^_]*_([^-]*)-.*$/\1/'
```

**Using awk:**

```
awk -F '_' '{sub(/-.*$/, "", $3); print $3}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ foo='abc_defg_hijd-3.29.0-2_el6_11h.txt'
$ bar=${foo%%-*}                # remove everything after the first -
$ bar=${bar#*_}; bar=${bar#*_}  # remove everything before the second _
$ echo "${bar}"
hijd
```

Comment: this pure-`bash` solution is probably the best. You could guarantee splitting on the second underscore with two passes of `bar=${bar#*_}`, no?

Comment: Or a single expansion of `bar=${bar#*_*_}`

Answer (score 2):

**grep** was born to extract:

```
grep -oP '[^_-]*_\K[^_-]*(?=-)'
```

example

```
kent$  echo 'abc_defg_hijd-3.29.0-2_el6_11h.txt'|grep -oP '[^_-]*_\K[^_-]*(?=-)'
hijd
```

**awk** is nuclear bomb for text processing,but it can kill a fly for sure:

```
awk -F- 'split($1,a,"_")&&$0=a[3]'
```

or shorter(gawk):

```
awk -v FPAT="[^-_]*" '$0=$3'
```

example

```
kent$  echo 'abc_defg_hijd-3.29.0-2_el6_11h.txt'|awk -F- 'split($1,a,"_")&&$0=a[3]'  
hijd


kent$  echo 'abc_defg_hijd-3.29.0-2_el6_11h.txt'|awk -v FPAT="[^-_]*" '$0=$3'
hijd
```

Answer (score 0):

with `GNU sed`

```
echo 'abc_defg_hijd-3.29.0-2_el6_11h.txt' | 
sed 's/\([^_]\+_\)\{2\}\([^-]\+\)-.*/\2/g'
hijd
```

Answer (score 0):

windows batch:

```
for /f "tokens=3delims=_-" %%i in ("abc_defg_hijd-3.29.0-2_el6_11h.txt") do echo %%i
hijd
```